Disable errors when a regular expression is invalid
I have an application that runs arbitrary regular expressions coming from users (with the proper config of regexp_stack_limit and regexp_time_limit to cover most of the performance considerations) but queries throw errors when regular expressions are malformed which breaks some of our workflows.
mysql> select "a" regexp "(a|b";
ERROR 3691 (HY000): Mismatched parenthesis in regular expression.

There are many other regexp related errors:
ERROR 3684 (HY000): An output string could not be zero-terminated because the length exceeds the buffer capacity.
ERROR 3685 (HY000): Illegal argument to a regular expression.
ERROR 3686 (HY000): Index out of bounds in regular expression search.
ERROR 3687 (HY000): Internal error in the regular expression library.
ERROR 3688 (HY000): Syntax error in regular expression on line %u, character %u.
ERROR 3689 (HY000): Unrecognized escape sequence in regular expression.
ERROR 3690 (HY000): The regular expression contains a feature that is not implemented in this library version.
ERROR 3691 (HY000): Mismatched parenthesis in regular expression.
ERROR 3692 (HY000): Incorrect description of a {min,max} interval.
ERROR 3693 (HY000): The maximum is less than the minumum in a {min,max} interval.
ERROR 3694 (HY000): Invalid back-reference in regular expression.
ERROR 3695 (HY000): The look-behind assertion exceeds the limit in regular expression.
ERROR 3696 (HY000): The regular expression contains an unclosed bracket expression.
ERROR 3697 (HY000): The regular expression contains an [x-y] character range where x comes after y.
ERROR 3698 (HY000): Overflow in the regular expression backtrack stack.
ERROR 3699 (HY000): Timeout exceeded in regular expression match.
ERROR 3700 (HY000): The regular expression pattern exceeds limits on size or complexity.

Is there a way to soften these errors, and just return 0 if the regexp pattern is invalid?
For example:
mysql> select "a" regexp "(a|b";
+--------------------+
|  "a" regexp "(a|b" |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+


There are no system variables or SQL modes other than the two you listed. So I don't think there's a way to configure this error. You'll need to check for it in the application language.

It's a terrible idea to allow users to submit regular expressions — or any other part of code. This is SQL injection. Instead, keep a set of pre-vetted regular expressions in your application, and allow them to choose one.

I agree with disallowing them but perhaps prepare/try/catch in a stored procedure could work to test if they are valid

https://xkcd.com/327/

Unsure why it is an SQL injection if the pattern is properly sent in a prepared statement?

Missing the point. Let's forget about whether it is "SQL injection" per se. It's still a bad design to allow users to submit any code and to execute that code verbatim.

Thank you for your answers Mr Karwin. I'm aware of the imperfections but these queries are run on dedicated databases for the purpose of adding flexibility to our app, it's always difficult to find the right balance and hopefully the implementation isn't that bad.

"prepare" adds quoting, but does nothing for the various syntax issues within a regular expression.  ( has special meaning.

I've found a way by creating a stored function containing an exit handler.
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION matches_regex(_text_to_validate TEXT,_pattern TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE error_code INT;
    DECLARE error_message VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 error_code = MYSQL_ERRNO, error_message = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        IF error_code IN (3684, 3685, 3686, 3687, 3688, 3689, 3690, 3691, 3692, 3693, 3694, 3695, 3696, 3697, 3698, 3699, 3700) THEN
            RETURN FALSE;
        ELSE
            RESIGNAL;
        END IF;
    END;

    RETURN _text_to_validate REGEXP _pattern;
END//

DELIMITER ;

Result:
mysql> select matches_regex("a", "(a|b");
+----------------------------+
| matches_regex("a", "(a|b") |
+----------------------------+
|                          0 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select matches_regex("a", "(a|b)");
+-----------------------------+
| matches_regex("a", "(a|b)") |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

